# Интерпретация в консоли смены элементов при пузырьковой сортировке

Tags: c++

написал код пузырьковой сортировки на C++.Помогите,пожалуйста,сделать так,чтобы в консоли отображалась смена элементов при каждой итерации цикла(еще чтобы элементы,которые меняются местами , были подсвечены каким-либо цветом).Спасибо.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> k;
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        k.push_back(temp);
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j < n - 1;j++) {
                if(k[j] > k[j + 1]) {
                    swap(k[j],k[j+1]);
                }
        }
    }
     for(auto s : k) {
        cout << s << " ";
     }


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::fixed;
using std::setw;

#define on , // So I can use the function - void text(text_color on background_color)

HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

// My text color function. Use it if you wish.
void text(int text_color = 0 on int paper_color = 7)
{
    // defaults to black on light_gray
    const int color_total = (text_color + (paper_color * 16));
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), color_total);
}

enum Colors
{
    black,
    //  0 text color - multiply by 16, for background colors
    dark_blue,
    //  1
    dark_green,
    //  2
    dark_cyan,
    //  3
    dark_red,
    //  4
    dark_magenta,
    //  5
    dark_yellow,
    //  6
    light_gray,
    //  7
    dark_gray,
    //  8
    light_blue,
    //  9
    light_green,
    // 10
    light_cyan,
    // 11
    light_red,
    // 12
    light_magenta,
    // 13
    light_yellow,
    // 14
    white // 15
};

void sort_array_ascending(int* array, int size);
void print_array(int* array, int* old_array, int);
void print_unsorted_array(int* array, int size);

int main()
{
    text(light_green on black);

    const string title = "Array Sorting Program";

    const string hyphen(100, '-');

    constexpr int size = 10;
    int values[size] = {39, 19, 74, 82, 80, 95, 94, 48, 29, 8};

    cout << hyphen << endl;
    cout << "                                         " << title << endl;
    cout << hyphen << endl;

    cout << "\n              This program will sort two identical arrays of numbers using a Bubble Sort" << endl;


    cout << "\n                                       Array 1 -- Ascending Order:   \n" << endl;

    print_unsorted_array(values, size);

    cout << endl;
    sort_array_ascending(values, size);
    text(light_green on black);
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\t\t\tPress only the 'Enter' key to exit program: ";
    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    cin.get();
}

void sort_array_ascending(int* array, int size)
{
    constexpr int swapped_color = 4;

    int old_array[8];
    bool swapTookPlace;
    int pass = 0;

    do
    {
        swapTookPlace = false;
        for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++)
        {
            if (array[count] > array[count + 1])
            {
                constexpr int non_swapped_color = 2;
                for (int a = 0; a < size; a++)
                {
                    old_array[a] = array[a];
                }
                swapTookPlace = true;

                text(non_swapped_color on black);;
                const int temp = array[count];
                array[count] = array[count + 1];
                array[count + 1] = temp;

                cout << fixed << setw(2) << " Pass # " << (pass < 9 ? "  " : " ") << (pass + 1) << " : ";
                pass += 1;
                print_array(&array[0], old_array, size);
            }
        }
    }
    while (swapTookPlace);
    text(swapped_color on black);
}

void print_array(int* array, int* old_array, int size)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < size; ++count)
    {
        if (array[count] != old_array[count])
        {
            constexpr int swapped_color = 12;
            text(swapped_color on black);
        }
        else
        {
            constexpr int non_swapped_color = 10;
            text(non_swapped_color on black);
        }

        cout << "   " << array[count] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void print_unsorted_array(int* array, int size)
{
    cout << "  Unsorted    ";
    for (int count = 0; count < size; ++count)
    {
        cout << "   " << array[count] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------";
}
```